# Spring in Action III - 1 chapter 1 example and app is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I just started learning Spring with Spring in action 3rd edition and I already have a problem with first chapter - example about a knight. Everything was ok, but when I wrote the code in beans.xml with aop my application stopped working, here's a source code of beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

<bean id="knight" class="com.mol.spring.action.classes.BraveKnight">
    <constructor-arg ref="dragonquest" />
</bean>

<bean id="dragonquest" class="com.mol.spring.action.classes.DragonSlayingQuest" />
<bean id="damselquest" class="com.mol.spring.action.classes.DamselResquingQuest" />
<bean id="minstrel" class="com.mol.spring.action.classes.Minstrel" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="minstrel">
        <aop:pointcut id="embark" expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..))" />
        <aop:before method="singBeforeQuest" pointcut-ref="embark" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
</beans>
```

Everything worked fine, until I wrote the `<aop:config>` and app works if I comment the `<aop:before />` tag. If other classes are needed, I'll include them.

Error message:

```
kwi 03, 2014 1:29:45 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3abc8690: startup date [Thu Apr 03 13:29:45 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
kwi 03, 2014 1:29:45 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans.xml]
kwi 03, 2014 1:29:46 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@14b05b39: defining beans [knight,dragonquest,damselquest,minstrel,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,embark]; root of factory hierarchy
kwi 03, 2014 1:29:46 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@14b05b39: defining beans [knight,dragonquest,damselquest,minstrel,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0,embark]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'knight' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'embark' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embark': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:454)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.mol.spring.action.BraveKnightTest.main(BraveKnightTest.java:12)
```

I cut out everything that's below, I don't think it matters.

Comment: and what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the aspectj JARs in your classpath.

Try adding this to your POM.XML

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Just check if the versions are compatible.

Btw if you are not using Maven try adding the respective JARs.